# Opencart "sent" message

Tags: email, opencart, message

How can we edit the "SENT" (javascript alert) that is generated after the customer sends a message? For example, "Thank you very much for your message, we will get back to you as soon as possible."

Comment: which is your actual version of opencart ?

Comment: opencart version : 3.0.3.2

Comment: Please provide the scenario in which you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code.

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Alert</h2>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("Thank you very much for your message, we will get back to you as soon as possible.");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

i think it's very helpful for you.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot but i mentioned about OPENCART system:) I think you didn't look topic